# mount失敗時のファイル復旧

Tags: ubuntu

以下のサイトを参考にしつつ、ファイルアップの上限を設けようという作業をしていたのですが、空の `xxx.fs` をマウントしてしまい既存のファイルを消してしまいました。
（たぶん消えていると思います。）

[quotaを使用しないディレクトリ単位の容量制限](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/bitwaka/20090402/1239865912)

実行したコマンドは以下の通りです。

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/home/workin.fs bs=1G count=90
mke2fs /home/workin.fs
mount -o loop /home/workin.fs /home/work/tmp/mydir
```

また、`df -hT` の結果は以下の通りですっかり空になってしまっている感じです。

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      ext4      455G  299G  134G  70% /
none           tmpfs     4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev           devtmpfs  1.8G  4.0K  1.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     353M   18M  335M   6% /run
none           tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none           tmpfs     1.8G  144K  1.8G   1% /run/shm
none           tmpfs     100M   32K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/loop0     ext2       89G   56M   85G   1% /home/work/tmp/mydir　←ココ
```

`rm` の削除の場合などは

[Linuxでうっかりrm -rfしちゃったけど復活出来たよー＼(＾o＾)／](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/y-kawaz/20110123/1295779916)

というところで、`extundelete` コマンドが紹介されておりましたが、果たしてマウントでファイルを空にしてしまった場合、このような方法で復旧が可能でしょうか？
（これはそもそもext3,ext4以外では使えないでしょうか。）

私が実行したコマンドは0埋めで削除してしまっているため、安易に実行しない方がよいのかなととも考えております。
また単にrmしたわけではないので、lsofも本件に至っては駄目なのでは？と思っております。

もしここらのファイルシステムに詳しい方おられましたらご教授お願いいたします。

ちなみに消してしまったファイルはシステムに関係のないファイルだけなのでOS自体は健康な状態です。よろしくお願いいたします。

**OS情報**

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04 LTS"
```

Comment: よく分からないのですが、`/home/woking.fs` をマウントする以前の `/home/work/tmp/mydir/` ディレクトリ以下のファイルが無事かどうか？という事でしょうか？

Comment: 確認です。空になった、というのはどこのことでしょうか? (`/home/workin.fs`の中身、`/home/work/tmp/mydir`以下のファイル、その他)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ご指摘のとおり/home/work/tmp/mydirが空になりました。/home/workin.fsが空なので上書きされたという認識でおります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

削除の操作をしていないのであれば、マウント解除で元に戻らないでしょうか。

私の場合は以前、/home以下にサブディレクトリがあるにも関わらず別の領域(NFS)を
マウントしてしまい、元あったファイルが一時的に参照できなくなった事がありますが、
unmoutする事でローカルにあるファイルが再度正常に見えるようになりました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。cubickさんおっしゃる通り、いろいろな方法ある中でunmountを試してみたいと思います。

Comment: mount -o loopでループデバイスを使ってマウントしているという認識ですが、unmount時は、単に
unmount /home/workin.fs
でよいものでしょうか。(やってみるしかないですよね。。）

Comment: すみません。文法が逆でした。
umount /home/work/tmp/mydirが正しかったです

Comment: とはいえ、umount /home/work/tmp/mydir: デバイスがビジーです。
       (このデバイスがプロセスによって使われているのであれば、lsof(8)やfuser(1)を使って調査するのが有益かもしれません)というエラーが出ました。ちょっといろいろ調査します。

Comment: マウント中のディレクトリにシェルで移動しているとunmountで来ませんので、$HOMEや/tmpに移動してからunmountを試してみては。

Comment: 諸々ありがとうございます。移動後にumountしましたが結局プロセスが残っていてダメでした。kill -9 1234ではダメで、kill -kill 1234を何度かやってやっと消えてくれた感じでした。その後umountして無事ファイルが戻ってきました。ありがとうございます。